# Unable to access protected method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was learning the concept of encapsulation in ruby.

Below is the sample code, Laptop inherits from Machine, i have made eat a protected method (Machine class), but can't access through Laptop's instance.

Also, i am not able to access the Laptop's protected method called description.

```
class Machine

  attr_accessor :name,:cost  generated

  protected
  def eat
    puts "machine don't eat"
  end

end


class Laptop < Machine

  private
  def ram
    return "4gb"
  end

  private
  def core
    return "i3"
  end

  protected
  def description
    puts "The laptop has #{ram} ram and it has #{core} core"
  end
end

laptop=Laptop.new
laptop.name="hp_notebook_15_n205tx"
laptop.cost =44000

puts "laptop is a machine, & #{laptop.eat} "  #doesn't work
puts "#{laptop.name} costs #{laptop.cost}"
puts "#{laptop.description}"                  #doesn't work
```

Below is the error which i have got:

```
`<top (required)>': protected method `eat' called for #<Laptop:0x2ed3b68 @name="hp_notebook_15_n205tx", @cost=44000> (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The visibility or access of methods and constants may be set with the
  methods public, private, or protected.
- Ruby doesn't allow you to access or change the instance variable form
  outside of the class. For overcoming this you have to use accessor
  methods
- Private methods can only be called within the class and not from an
  instance of class itself also it is not used with the self keyword
- Protected methods can only be called by methods encapsulated in the class or subclass itself,not directly from an instance of a class/subclass.

  ```
   class Machine
    attr_accessor :name,:cost

    # All the methods below the  protected keyword will be protected
    protected

    def eat
      puts "machine don't eat"
    end

    def sleep
      puts "machine don't sleep"
    end

  end

  machine=Machine.new
  machine.name ="Keyword"
  puts "The name of the machine is #{machine.name}"

  # NoMethodError  because of accessing the protected methods via an object of Machine
  # puts machine.eat
  # puts machine.sleep

  class Laptop < Machine

    # All the method below the private keyword be will private
    private

    def ram                                 # private method
      return "4gb"
    end

    def core                                # private method
      return "i3"
    end

    # all the methods below the protected keyword will be protected
    public

    def description
      puts "The laptop has #{ram} ram and it has #{core} core"
    end

    def laptopActivity
      eat
      sleep
    end
  end

  laptop=Laptop.new
  laptop.name="hp_notebook_15_n205tx"
  laptop.cost =44000

  # puts "laptop is a machine, & #{laptop.eat}"   NoMethodError coz trying to access protected method through the object
  puts "#{laptop.name} costs #{laptop.cost}"     #accessing public method of Machine through the laptop object
  puts "#{laptop.description}"                   # made description public ( description method calls private method of laptop class)
  puts laptop.laptopActivity                     # calling protected methods of parent class (inheritance)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Protected methods can only be called by methods encapsulated in the class or subclass itself, not directly from an instance of a class/subclass. If you want the `eat` method to be called from an instance than make it public or call it from another public method:

```
[19] pry(main)> class Machine
[19] pry(main)*   protected
[19] pry(main)*   def eat
[19] pry(main)*     puts "eating"
[19] pry(main)*   end
[19] pry(main)* end
:eat
[20] pry(main)> class Laptop < Machine
[20] pry(main)*   def chow
[20] pry(main)*     self.eat
[20] pry(main)*   end
[20] pry(main)* end
:chow
[21] pry(main)> l = Laptop.new
#<Laptop:0x007f9c92b5c968>
[22] pry(main)> l.chow
eating
nil
```

Comment: A method marked protected means that it can be used only by instances of the class where it was defined, or by derived classes.   Source: Learning Ruby by Michael Fitzgerald.

Comment: Also refer:  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes

Comment: saying can be used by instances of the class is misleading and pretty much untrue. It can be used by the class and sublcasses INTERNALLY. The difference between private and protected is that private methods cannot be used by subclasses.

Comment: Yes. But you are not using it in an instance of the class where it was defined or in a derived class. You are using it at the top-level, i.e. in `Object`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag , see the description method of Laptop class, also in ruby does creating instance doesn't means creating an object ?

Comment: Yes. `description` is protected. Which means you can call it in `Laptop` and all its subclasses. But you are calling it in `Object`, which is not a subclass of `Laptop`.

Comment: You are calling it `on` an instance of `Laptop`, not `in` an instance of `Laptop`.. does that explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can not reach protected or private methods from outside for ruby except dynamic dispatching. I mean `laptop.eat` will raise exception, however, `laptop.send(:eat)` will make run the method. This is dynamic dispatching.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: This is explained in the documentation, in the language specification, and in very Ruby book, Ruby tutorial, and Ruby course.